# How to use multiple order_by in single Django query with conditions based on field values

Tags: django, orm, sql-order-by, django-queryset

How can I make **order_by** fields in a single query dependent on field values?

e.g.,

- if field *status==10* then sort ascending
- if field *status==20* then sort descending

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [conditions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-expressions) in your `order_by` like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

Model.objects.order_by(
    Case(When(status='10', then='some_field')).asc(),
    Case(When(status='20', then='some_field')).desc())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I need!